# Modular Arithmetic - Proof or Counterexample

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

True or false: if x ≡ 1 (mod 5) and y ≡ 1 (mod 5), then gcd(x, y) ≡ 1 (mod 5). If true, prove it; if false, give a counterexample.

Note: The statement refers to all pairs x, y. To prove it, it needs to hold for all x, y, but to refute it, it is necessary to only provide one counterexample.

Having a lot of trouble with this one. Originally I thought it was true, but I can't come up with a sound proof. Is it potentially false? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: The counterexample $x=6,y=21$ would be sufficient, right?

Comment: Have you tried listing a few numbers the relevant congruence class and seeing what happens?

Comment: Does 6 and 21 work? My computation shows that it doesn't.

Comment: So your computation is wrong: Dividing $6$ by $5$ leaves a remainder of $1$, which is also the remainder when dividing $21$ by $5$. However, the greatest common divisor of $6$ and $21$ is not $1$, that is, they are not relatively prime, in fact, the number $3$ is their greatest common divisor.

Comment: A "simpler" example: x=6 and y=16